# PHP autodoc(Inheritance) autodocumentor tags

Tags: php, phpdoc

I am using phpautodocumentor, I am writing a class which extends a class which is in completely different folder, How can I write in comments that I am extending that particular class. Because intellisense in visual studio or Aptana doesn't recognize. The code works fine.The problem is documenting. It doesn't say I am extending so and so class in documentation

Answer (score 0):

There's no tag for extending, your IDE should realize it from the code, good ones - like PDT, Zend Studio or PhpStorm - do. However, there's a @see tag to refer to other content in the docs.

```
 /** 
  * this class extends main_class.
  * @see main_class, TEST_CONST
  */
  subclass extends main_class {
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

(from the perspective of phpDocumentor, docblocks in general, and IDE popup help...)

Ideally, the IDE should recognize from the code that the current class is a child of another class, and show you info from the parent docblock on the child class's popup help.  However, if you put a docblock on the child class itself and write info there that duplicates sections from the parent docblock (short description, long description, @param, @return), then the child docblock info will sometimes "override" the parent info, effectively preventing the popup from showing any parent info at all.

If I make a docblock on a child class or inherited items, I'll stick with only using tags in them other than @param and @return, so that the child docblock info augments the parent info rather than replace it.  Generally, though, I won't put a docblock on inherited methods since I don't need it to show anything beyond what's already given in the parent's docblock.

---

(from the perspective of "phpautodocumentor", which I don't know of, and Aptana, which I don't use but is presumed to be an Eclipse derivative...)

I have assumed that you are mainly referring to the IDE's popup help showing you parent class info when you highlight the child class.

Instead, if you are referring to something that is generating actual class documentation separately from IDE file editing, then nothing should generally be required other than the code itself.  phpDocumentor certainly recognizes class inheritance from the code alone, and will show inherited things in their own section in most of the output converters.  If "phpautodocumentor" is something else, then I can't speak to what its capabilities are.